# JavaScript and jQuery , creating and usng an object. Properties return undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, callback

```
function DialogWindow(contents, clickEvent){
// given a contents we can create a DialogWindow of that content
this.contents = contents;
this.domElement = $(".hideMe");

this.test = function(){
    console.log(this.contents);
}

$("div").click(this.test); //<-note this spot

/*
This function simply returns the html representation of the contents
This function should be called withen WindowPage so that it can fully figure out what
Arguments:
    container: the container that containes the WindowPage that this is apart of
    lanes: the number of lanes on the page. Defined as: lanes = (number of columns in WindowPage) * 3 + 1
*/
this.toHtml = function(container, lanes){

    var dialogWidth = container.width()/(lanes/2);
    var dialogSep = container.width()/lanes;

    var htmlWindow = jQuery('<div/>', {
        id: "dialogWindow"
    }).css("width", dialogWidth).css("height", dialogWidth).css("position","absolute");

    jQuery(this.contents.toHtml()).appendTo(htmlWindow);

    this.domElement = htmlWindow;

    return htmlWindow;
}
```

}

My goal is to get a click of htmlWindow, to execute a function of DialogWindow. However whenever I do this all of DialogWindows properties return undefined. If I replace the line:

```
$("div").click(this.test);
```

with

```
$("div").click(this.test());
```

Then the function test() fires imediatelly and works (i.e. prints this.contents to the console). However if I leave that line as it was (i.e. I wait for a click to make the test() function fire) then it prints undefined to the console.

Answer (score 0):

It is because `this` inside `test` does not point to DialogWindow object, it points to the clicked dom element

One solution is to pass a custom execution proxy to the event callback using [$.proxy()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.proxy/)

```
this.test = function(){
    console.log(this.contents);
}
$("div").click($.proxy(this.test, this)); //<-note this spot
```

Another popular solution is to use a closure variable

```
var self = this
this.test = function(){
    console.log(self.contents);
}
$("div").click(this.test); //<-note this spot
```

In this scenario I'll prefer to use the former method

Comment: So I had been at this for quite a while. About 5 minutes after I posted this I figured out that I could do it with the var self = this idea. So that's what I went with. I'm glad to see that I am not doing something completely crazy at least.